# what are the hot areas/future in computer science/machine learning in the next decade?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, statistics, reinforcement-learning, mathematics

what are the hot areas in computer science/machine learning in the next decade ? I am interested in knowing this since deep learning/machine learning which dominated in the last decade has saturated almost .

Answer (score 1):

Super broad question, however, in case you want to keep it more down-to-earth then MLOps will certainly get increasingly important. After peak hype we'll see peak adoption into everyday businesses - someone has to deploy and maintain those machine learning systems. Another area will be low-code/no-code solutions as I really don't think we are anywhere near 'saturation', but most untouched areas/businesses will get the advantages of machine learning via respective tools that don't require in-depth knowledge. With that, machine learning will become more focused on software application rather than actual development.

If you are disappointed and want to get more fancy maybe quantum machine learning - who knows? Since the disparity in AI regarding progress on different levels and in different areas increasingly grows, I think there will be many opportunities in different niches in AI. All depends on your definition of 'hot'.